# Break a for loop with a KeyEvent in java

Tags: java

How can I break a for loop (outside the listener) when a KeyEvent occur (pressed the S key) ? I tried to do it but it doesn't work.

This is the listener :

```
public class ListenKey implements KeyListener{

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S) 
            Spressed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S) 
            Spressed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S) 
            Spressed = true;
    }

}
```

And this is the for loop :

```
for(int i=1; i<=times; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((int)(speed*1000));
                        (new Robot()).mouseMove((int)Math.abs(((r.nextInt())%(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth())+1)), 
                                                (int)Math.abs(((r.nextInt())%(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight())+1)));
                    } catch (InterruptedException | AWTException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(Spressed == true) {
                        System.out.println("S");
                        Spressed = false;
                        break;  
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to create a program that make the mouse jump around, just for entertaining purpose :) but I want the users to be able to stop the mouse when they pressed the S key

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop usually works better for what you're trying to accomplish than a `for` loop. Assuming that your class sets `Spressed` to false before the loop, here's what the code would be:

```
while (!Spressed) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep((int)(speed*1000));
        (new Robot()).mouseMove((int)Math.abs(((r.nextInt())%(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth())+1)), 
        (int)Math.abs(((r.nextInt())%(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight())+1)));
    } catch (InterruptedException | AWTException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println("S");
Spressed = false;
break;
```

Also, you should follow [Java variable naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and call it `sPressed` instead of `Spressed`.

Comment: I tried to do what you told me, but it seem to print out S after the while loop is end, But I found the solution myself, I putted the while loop in a thread, then when an event happen, just stop that thread and that worked.